# Xdebug stops at non-existing breakpoints in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Most of the time, I have no problems Xdebug debugging my PHP code in VS Code. But lately, VS Code has started ignoring my breakpoints and instead stopping at random function declarations.

i.e. it will stop at `function x($a)` in the function below instead of stopping at the breakpoint:

```
function x($a) {
    // Some code, including a line with a breakpoint
}
```

Even though the debugging stops at function declarations, I can't step into the code in the functions. Aka. I can't debug anything :panic:

My launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9090
},
{
    "name": "Launch currently open script",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "port": 9090
}
]
```

Any ideas for fixing this, so my Xdebug debugging will start behaving again?

I have tried restarting VS Code and Apache + changed port numbers. Didn't help.

Versions on my system:

- System: Windows NT LAPTOP-612BINLI 10.0 build 19041 (Windows 10) AMD64
- Apache Version: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.3.31
- Xdebug Version: 2.8.1

Comment: Sure you have the latest version?

Comment: Latest version of what? It has worked before. For some reason it stopped working a few days ago.

Comment: @Mads Start with stating your OS, PHP and Xdebug versions as well as showing your Xdebug config. You can get all that from `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: Good point. Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running an unsupported PHP and Xdebug version. This is a known problem that was fixed in Xdebug 2.9.1. The problem comes from the `resolved_breakpoints` issue implemented in the php-debug extension.
As a workaround you can disable this feature by adding this to your `launch.json` configuration

```
      "xdebugSettings": {
        "resolved_breakpoints": "0"
      },
```

A more in depth analysis and links to Xdebug issue can be found in my last response:
https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/629

However this should not stop you from stepping further.
Do you have some variables in you watch panel? In Xdebug before 3.1.0 `eval`ing broken code caused the debug engine to stop running correctly (exceptions were not caught correctly).

Comment: Awesome. Updating my Xdebug to version 2.9.7 fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for fixing my debugging headache! :)